# Spring 3 PropertyEditorSupport setAsText not invoked for objectify customer editor

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, objectify

I am using spring and I have a child model with a objectify key object - "Key parent"

The getAsText prints ok when form is being loaded, but when the form submit, setAsText is skipped. Any reason? and the parentType is empty when it arrives the Controller. Is it the form issue or controller or the editor?

(side track: Is there an editor written for Objectify Key <-> String mapping?)

Jsp

```
<form:hidden path="parentType"  />
```

Controller

```
    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request,
            ServletRequestDataBinder binder) throws Exception {


        /** Key Conversion **/
        binder.registerCustomEditor(com.googlecode.objectify.Key.class,  new KeyEditor());
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/subtype-formsubmit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView subTypeFormSubmit(@ModelAttribute("productSubType") @Valid ProductSubType productSubType,
            BindingResult result){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

        //OK, getting the value
        log.info(productSubType.getType()); 

            //NOT OK, productSubType.getParentType() always null, and setAsText is not called?!
        log.info(productSubType.getParentType().toString()); 

        return mav;
    }
```

KeyEditor.java

```
public class KeyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

private static final Logger log = Logger
        .getLogger(KeyEditor.class.getName());

public KeyEditor(){
    super();
}

@Override
public String getAsText() {
    Long id = ((Key) getValue()).getId();
    String kind = ((Key) getValue()).getKind();
    log.info(kind + "." + id.toString());
    return kind + "." + id.toString();
}

@Override
public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    log.info(text);
    String clazz = text.substring(0, text.indexOf("."));
    Long id = Long.parseLong(text.substring(text.indexOf(".")));
    log.info(clazz+":"+id);
    Class c=null;
    Key<?> key=null;
    try {
        c = Class.forName(clazz);
        key = new Key(c, id);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.info("ex" + ex.toString());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    setValue(key);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `Class.forName` with the complete class name, including packages.

I think that `Key#getKind()` returns the simple class name without packages. Also `text.substring(0, text.indexOf("."));` (in setAsText) tells me there are no dots in `clazz`, so you're not feeding the correct input to `Class.forName`

Options:

- if all your classes are in the same package, then just prepend that to `clazz` (not a very robust solution)
- Since you have to register all of your entities anyway (`ObjectifyService.register(YourEntity.class);`), then you can simultaneously create a map from kind to complete class name, and then use it in `setAsText`.

But there might be better options...

Comment: instead of writing my own objectify key <-> string mechanism. I found that I can do

String keyString = ((Key) getValue()).getString(); // key to string
--
Key<?> key = Key.create(text); // String to key

so key is now web-safe string. when it is used in the view layer